# Why can't I translate parts of my mesh with the 3d widget?

Tags: modeling, transforms

I'm new to Blender, when I was working on a simple character like in the tutorial I'm following. I tried to change the shape of 2 cubes by moving the x and y arrows on the widget but it's not working and it doesn't even give me an arrow shape when I use box select. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three main transformations available: *Translate*, *Rotate*, and *Scale*.

## Keyboard shortcuts:

- Grab (<kbd>G</kbd>) (aka translate/move)
- Rotate (<kbd>R</kbd>)
- Scale (<kbd>S</kbd>)

From the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Manipulators#Manipulator_controls):

> the normal Transform commands (G for Grab, R for Rotation, S for Scale), can be used to manipulate objects along any axis.

## Widgets:

You can also use the the [transform manipulator widgets](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Manipulators#Manipulator_controls) to do this by pressing on the arrows with <kbd>LMB</kbd>.

You can enable or disable the transform manipulator widget by pressing the [image] icon in *3D view > Header*:

[image]

Or by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>.

You can change the transofm manipulator type by selecting one of the buttons again in the *Header* of the *3D view*:

- *Location* ([image])
- *Rotation* ([image])
- *Scale* ([image])

It sounds like you want *Location* manipulators, but you have *Scale* type selected.

Try setting it like this by pressing one of the icons:

[image]

Also note that you can select multiple widgets at once by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> while selecting them.

Answer (score 0):

I did change Nvidia to Radeon. After that clicking on the vidget axis doesn't work (it only changes the 3d cursor location). Found this solution on a forum: File-User prefs-System-Selection-**OpenGL Select** (Not Auto).

Answer (score 0):

It also happened to me. And it wasn't just the gizmo, also de camera orbit wasn't working properly... Finally I discovered that somehow I locked the view to an Object
[image]

Deleting the object link made averything work fine again.