# How to change to spherical Axis

Tags: customization

I was wondering how you change the way the axis to become spherical?
[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6394/599

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have changed the manipulator widget to rotate mode, to return to the default (translate) mode, select the pointer icon as selected below.

[image: Transform Manipulator Widget]

There are many options for using the widget, detailed documentation can be found about its usage on the Blender Wiki.

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Manipulators#Manipulators