# 3d Manipulator not working

Tags: transforms

I am working on building a model car. I found that the manipulators won't work. The X, Y, Z axis don't do anything except move my 3D Cursor to where I clicked. I tried the Translation manipulator, Rotation manipulator, and the Scale manipulator. Is there anyway I can fix these manipulators so that they can work again?

Comment: @Comrade Vader I didn't see any issue with the wording there.

Comment: Sounds like a left-click/right-click issue. When I have my preferences set to selecting with left-click, right-click will only move the 3D cursor as you describe.

Comment: Well left click moves the 3D cursor like it does in 2.70 and 2.71 version of blender. Right click for me selects the object and moves it wherever without any axis constraints. I attempted to research and found that switching the mouse buttons the other way around didn't do the trick. Any other way?

Comment: You can also use `G` `R` and `S`, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/6395/599

Comment: @gandalf3 Is that 2.72b though? I don't think that question is focused on Blender 2.72b. My quest is about 2.72b and need to really know how to fix these manipulators.

Comment: @7Blue_Beast7 AFAIK nothing with the manipulator has changed recently, so everything in that answer should apply to 2.72b. If it still doesn't help, try reloading the default setup by pressing *File > Load factory settings*.

Comment: @gandalf3 I tried and nothing works but ima go ahead and re-install blender.

Comment: Reinstalling did nothing @gandalf3

Comment: @RayMairlot So how do I enables my transformation widgets to respond upon click?

Comment: @7Blue_Beast7 You shouldn't have to do anything. Are you sure you are left clicking? (sorry, but it should just work..)

Comment: @7Blue_Beast7 If all else fails you can always try submitting a bug report, see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports

Comment: I solved the problem thanks to Blender.org